# Does order of the states in the if statement matter?

Tags: java, if-statement, statements

from line 5 on my code which is,

```
if (i + 2 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == 'y' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'k')
```

Does the order of statements matter? I was wondering because

when I assign **str = "yak123ya"**

`(i + 2 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == 'y' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'k')` works perfectly fine
but

`(str.charAt(i) == 'y' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'k' && i + 2 < str.length())` causes

error

> StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8 (line:5)

```
public String stringYak(String str) {
  String result = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (i + 2 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == 'y' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'k') {
      i += 2;
    } else {
      result += str.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: `&&` is a short-circuit operator, read **and then**. If the left hand side evaluates to `false` the right hand side is not evaluated (executed). This allows index checking left, and index using right. The same for `||` aka **or else**

Comment: Thank you so much for your input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expressions are evaluated left to right, with short-circuiting. That means when an expression `a && b` is evaluated, and `a` evaluates to `false`, the whole expression evaluates to `false` without executing `b`.

In this case, when `i = 6`, `i + 2 < str.length()` is `false`, and therefore the `charAt(6)` is not executed (and therefore not throwing an exception).

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand why the order of the statements matters

Answer (score 2):

yes for sure order matters. as in this if statement
(i + 2 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == 'y' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'k')
if the first condition which is i + 2 < str.length() is false, it will not check the second condition which is str.charAt(i) == 'y' so it will not throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Thank you so much for the input! Your explanation for the exception really helped me fix the error